# Android Rotation Error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I having trouble with my android app. I have two edit text and two radiogroups consisting of several radiobuttons. I have a navigation drawer with fragments.

When the user types in a number and chooses the radiobutton, it changes that number to a final number. However when the android device is rotated to be horizontal, the radiobuttons resets to the initial checked, and resets the edittext value. I want it so that the edittext value and radiobutton to stay the same.

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public static RadioButton button1a;
    public static RadioButton button2a;
    public static RadioButton button3a;
    public static RadioButton button4a;
    public static RadioButton button5a;

    public static RadioButton button1b;
    public static RadioButton button2b;
    public static RadioButton button3b;
    public static RadioButton button4b;
    public static RadioButton button5b;

    public static EditText valueinput;
    public static EditText valueoutput;

    public static double valueInputvar;
    public static double valueOutputvar;

    public static RadioGroup g1, g2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            valueinput.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("input"));
            valueinput.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("output"));
            g1.check(savedInstanceState.getInt("n1"));
            g2.check(savedInstanceState.getInt("n2"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("input", valueinput.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("output", valueoutput.getText().toString());
        outState.putInt("n1", g1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        outState.putInt("n2", g2.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);

        g1 = (RadioGroup) content.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        g2 = (RadioGroup) content.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);


        button1a = (RadioButton) content.findViewById(R.id.radio1a);
        button2a = (RadioButton) content.findViewById(R.id.radio2a);
        button3a = (RadioButton) content.findViewById(R.id.radio3a);
        button4a = (RadioButton) content.findViewById(R.id.radio4a);
        button5a = (RadioButton) content.findViewById(R.id.radio5a);

        button1b = (RadioButton) content.findViewById(R.id.radio1b);
        button2b = (RadioButton) content.findViewById(R.id.radio2b);
        button3b = (RadioButton) content.findViewById(R.id.radio3b);
        button4b = (RadioButton) content.findViewById(R.id.radio4b);
        button5b = (RadioButton) content.findViewById(R.id.radio5b);

        valueinput = (EditText) content.findViewById(R.id.value1);
        valueoutput = (EditText) content.findViewById(R.id.value2);

        valueinput.setHint("Enter a number");

        valueinput.setText(df.format(1));
        valueoutput.setText(df.format(1000));

        valueInputvar = Double.parseDouble(valueinput.getText().toString());
        valueOutputvar = Double.parseDouble(valueoutput.getText().toString());

        valueInputvar = 0;
        valueOutputvar = 0;

        });


        return content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, one problem in your onCreate (both were valueinput, this is the fixed version):

```
valueinput.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("input"));
valueoutput.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("output"));
```

The second thing you need to know is that onCreate is called before onCreateView as you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). So you have to change your logic slightly. You should notice that onCreateView also gets passed the savedInstanceState. Check if it is null, then initialize default values. Otherwise get values from bundle.

Answer (score 0):

use onSaveInstanceState to save the values and onRestoreInstanceState to get the values that you have entered.
For example :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putString("value_name", editText1.getText().toString().trim());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    editText1.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("value_name").trim());

}
```

Comment: After rotating the screen, onCreate method will be invoked so all the views  values will be reseed.  To save the last values of your views (such as EditText, RadioButton...) you have to use onSaveInstanceState. To get the values saved on onSaveInstanceState , you need to use onRestoreInstanceState.